# The inverse cumulative distribution of the product of two normally distributed variables

Tags: inverse-gaussian-distribution

Let me preface this by saying that I am not in any sense a statistician and I might be going about this totally wrong…

I am interested in calculating the inverse cumulative distribution of the product of two normally distributed variables (more specifically, I would like to find a number s.t. I can say with some arbitrary % confidence that that number is equal to or greater than the product of two variables, both of which follow normal distributions. Pretty sure I’m doing the right math for that but if not please let me know…). According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html, the distribution of the product of two such variables is a Bessel K function, and http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/21/01/01/0004/ gives the integral of K0 in terms of more Bessel Ks and some Struve L functions. Unfortunately none of those functions have simple expansions outside of specific domains, but in theory I could make like a Newton’s method solver or something to solve for the inverse cumulative distribution (also formula 11.1.9 in A&S might be useful, and section 11.5 has some notes on approximating Bessel integrals).

But that seems like a shit load of work so before I go down that path, I was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem before and knows a simpler way. Ideally I’d love to find something like 26.2.23 in A&S (https://www.johndcook.com/blog/normal_cdf_inverse/)…

Comment: Please clarify: although you appear to be asking about Normal distributions in full generality, the Wolfram page concerns only the product of *zero mean* Normal distributions.  Which situation are you in?

Comment: I do ultimately require means but I figured that would be a nearly trivial transformation of any result. If I have to brute force it the way I outlined I'll probably solve with zero mean and convert afterwards.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a trivial transformation at all: it's a significantly harder problem to deal with nonzero means.

Comment: Shit really? I was hoping I could just translate the Bessel K from u to u-xbar*ybar or something like that. Do you have a good source for information on working with these distribution-of-product-of-distributed-variables problems? I've been surprised at how hard it is to find info online; it seems like something that would come up a lot, but I guess it was naive to assume it's a common statistical problem.